# Tensor with multi-rank $(1,1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I want to Show that a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ tensor cannot have multi-rank $(1, 1, 2)$ and it has rank $1$ if and only
if it has multi-rank $(1, 1, 1)$?

Comment: Is this an assignment for a course?

Comment: Actually I don't know. My friend asked me and I tried to solved it but I couldn't. I think it is not an assignment because my friend doesn't study and doesn't have any course.

Answer (score 0):

If your tensor $T$ has multirank $(1,1,2)$ then it can be written in the form $a \otimes B$, where $B$ has multirank $(1,2)$. Then we can write the original tensor as $a \otimes b \otimes c$, where $c$ has rank $2$. But that is nonsense, $c$ is a vector in a vector space, so it has rank $1$ (unless $c=0$, but in that case your original tensor is zero).

If $T$ has rank $1$, then $T = a \otimes b \otimes c$ has multirank $(1,1,1)$.

If $T$ has multirank $(1,1,1)$, then $T = a \otimes B$ where $B$ has multirank $(1,1)$. So then $B = b \otimes c$. So $T = a \otimes b \otimes c$, and $T$ has rank $1$.